# custom constraint while updating Parent Entity Column in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, constraints

For example I have two tables Employee and Department and I am using

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Department department;
```

in Employee.
Here I want to add one constraint that, whenever one of the column of Department is updated to some value then it should not get updated if it has child records in Employee.

Can I achieve this by using CascadeType?
Or is there any other way by which I can define custom constraint?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to prohibit memory to database sync when Department is updated, then you're done as you have `insertable=false, update=false`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
```